Flutter: Scroll parrent Widget After child widget scroll reaches end, and when scroll parrent widget child widgets also scrolls

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key, required this.hideButtonController, required this.isTopAppBarVisible});
  final bool isTopAppBarVisible;
  final ScrollController hideButtonController ;
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  ScrollController parentController=ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// first listview
    return  SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: parentController,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height+100,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 50,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-100,
              /// Second Listview 
              child:  ListView(
                  controller: widget.hideButtonController,
                  children: [
                    for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
                     const SizedBox(
                         height: 50,
                         child: Center(child: Text("Home Screen", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green),))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I WANT TO SCROLL PARENT WIDGET AFTER CHILD WIDGET SCROLLS ENDS TOP OR BOTTOM.
i want to cutomize my project as app top bar of apk that is present at google play store with name of: jobsaf.
